# Dual Booting installation fails, leaves residual Ubuntu boot option, upon booting from it encounter GNU Grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Windows 10 installed already, and am trying to dual-boot with Ubuntu desktop(19.04). However, after finishing the dual-boot installation (allocating memory), Ubuntu asked for a restart, and upon restarting, my screen was filled with "squashfs" errors. After a long period of waiting, I decided to force shutdown. After turning my computer on from the shutdown, there was no Ubuntu dual-boot menu, and Windows was immediately booted. I decided to go to Window's disk management application (diskmgmt.msc) to delete the memory I allocated to my failed Ubuntu installation, and reattempt to install Ubuntu. However, when I am on the advanced startup page to attempt to boot from my USB to reinstall Ubuntu, [there is still an option to boot from Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjoK8.jpg), even though I already deleted the partition containing it. When I attempt to boot from it, [(can also be accessed from default boot menu upon computer startup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1r5K.jpg), I am  [greeted with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6eyk.jpg)
GNU Grub shell. Can anyone direct me on what I should do?

Comment: You can but do not need to remove Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi New install will just replace it. You have to boot USB live installer to reinstall.  Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode. And use Something Else install option to choose (change button) the same ext4 partition, if not deleted.  Do not use Windows to edit Linux partitions. Use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi